# Angular Firestore Unique name validation (Reactive Forms)

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-validation

I m new to Angular. I have configured project with FireStore. Everything is working fine. Now I want to register only those users who don't have account with us and give error message to those who are already registered.
Here is **register.component.ts**

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
    firstName: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3)
    ]),
    lastName: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3)
    ]),
    email: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email,
      CustomValidators.shouldBeUnique(this.afs)
    ])
});
```

And here is **Custom Validator ShouldBeUnique(afs)** method.

```js
static shouldBeUnique(afs: AngularFirestore): ValidationErrors | null{
    let emailExists: boolean;
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        let emailVal = ''
        let email = control.get('email').value;

        let collref = afs.collection('users').ref;
        let queryref = collref.where('email', '==', email);

        queryref.get().then((snapShot) => {
        if (snapShot.empty) {
            // this.status = 'valid';
            console.log('Email is avalible.');
            return null;
        }
        else {
            console.log('Email is already registered.');
                return { shouldBeUnique: true };
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

Code is working fine and returning **null** if email is not in DB. But problem with the code is when email exists in DB it only prints message in console and not returning  **{ shouldBeUnique: true };**.
Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: @frisinacho I don't know what you have changed in this question but I accepted the approval. Can you please mention the changes?

Comment: Hi @Musaddiq, I just edited the syntax to give a clearer view of the code (colours and highlights)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```js
queryref.get().then((snapShot) => {
    if (snapShot.empty) {
        // this.status = 'valid';
        console.log('Email is avalible.');
        return null;
    }
    else {
        console.log('Email is already registered.');
            return { shouldBeUnique: true };
        }
    });
```

You are trying to use the return inside the `then` function but that is a async execution and your code will not wait for that to finish. This is why the `console.log` is working but the return statement is not.

I suggest you use the async/await approach to reduce complexity and let me know if I can help you any further.

Comment: Thanks for the updates.
I m trying to use `async await` like below:
`await  queryref.get().then()` but having no luck.
Can you mention where I should use the `await` keyword? Or if you can give me full method with use of await it will great.

Comment: I've found a similar case in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47408765/8340339). This is a simple use of `await ref.get()`, remember the function containing the `await` call must be anotated as async.

Comment: I've followed this link but issue is the same.
Actually after writing the complete existing email address it only prints in console.
But when I press space bar after that it prints in console and also returns the message.