# Firebase returning two different outputs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've made a simple class that returns the data downloaded from firebase. The issue is that if I `console.log` data in the class, it gives data as expected. However, if I import this class anywhere else and try to use it, it returns data as undefined.

Can you explain what's wrong?

My getCollection func in class dbAPI (data is correct)

```
getCollection(collection) {
    dataBase
      .collection(collection)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        let data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
        console.log(data)
        return data
      })
      .catch(function(error) {})
  }
```

The way I try to get data (data is undefined here)

```
componentDidMount() {
  const db = new dbAPI()
  let data = db.getCollection("collectionName")
  this.setState({ data })}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to return data from a callback to a synchronous function, which is impossible ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)). You need to either promisify your `getCollection` function, or use async/await. If you want to convert your code to use async/await, check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401781/firebase-firestore-get-async-await). I put an example below. Basically, you need to await for the `get` request to get the data, then perform your transformation. After performing that transformation, you can return data.

```
async getCollection(collection) {
  const collectionRef = dataBase.collection(collection);
  try {
    const dataSnapshot = await collectionRef.get();
    const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }      
}
```

In your `componentDidMount`, you must add async/await keywords to the appropriate functions. Async needs to go to the top to mark `componentDidMount` as async, and you need to await the data from the function call `db.getCollection`.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const db = new dbAPI()
  const data = await db.getCollection("collectionName")
  this.setState({ data })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you I've managed to do it, really appreaciate your help, my solution:
getCollection:

```
 async getCollection(collection) {
let data = null
await dataBase
  .collection(collection)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(`Data fetch failed: \n${error}`)
    data = "ERROR"
  })
return data}
```

getting data:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
const db = new Database()
const data = await db.getCollection("collectionName")
this.setState({ ...data })}
```